# ComboBox in DataTemplate, items not highlighted on MouseOver

Tags: .net, wpf, combobox, datatemplate, highlight

Here's my question:
I have a ListBox binded to a list, in which the ItemTemplate is a DataTemplate that contains a ComboBox, so, for each item of my list I can show a different combobox.

Everything works fine,  with the exception that the items in the combobox are NOT highlighted. When I drop the combobox i see all the items, when i click on one of them it get selected in the combobox, but when mouse is over one of the items, it's still "white", it doesn't get darker as highlighted. I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

Did you edit the default styles? You can try and get the ComboBox ControlTemplate Example from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752094%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and change it accordingly to your needs. Another good tool to edit styles is the Expression Blend

Comment: I have the same problem & I tried this solution. Firstly, that template is not the default combo box - it looks different. I applied it both inside and outside of the DataTemplate. Inside, it still failed to highlight on mouse over the options. Outside, it highlighted just fine. So it seems that's not the solution. I am using .net 3.5.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it ! Add this inside your combo box:

```
<ComboBox.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}">#3399FF</SolidColorBrush>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}">White</SolidColorBrush>
</ComboBox.Resources>
```